# How to get user and token details after authenticating an App Service from Azure AD?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, token

I have a React Application for the Front end hosted on Azure in App Services. I also have another NodeJS app that I am using to create REST APIs for the front-end App. This App is hosted on another App Service.

Now, I want to integrate AD authentication for the front-end app using Azure Active Directory, which I have managed to do using the Easy Auth process. But I don't know how to get (or pass to the front end) the user and token details once the user is authenticated.

The second part of the query is, that I want to use the token to secure my REST APIs by passing it in the header and validating it in the backend. I have gone through various Microsoft documentation but I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Please help me in getting the user and token details. And please suggest how to secure my REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tokens via http headers or via an endpoint /.auth/me. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code

Regarding validating tokens, take a look at this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation

Comment: Thanks! I am able to get the tokens and user details in the front-end. Now I am trying to validate the access token by following this example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2
I am getting "authentication failed due to: invalid signature" error. Can you help further in debugging this?

Comment: I have explored further and tried to change the scope field as
 "scope": ["api://{client_id}/user_impersonation"]
But it has not affected anything.